# Car dies while driving

Tags: toyota, repair, camry

My 2007 Toyota Camry dies out while driving. 76000 mi well kept. New battery sensors and coils. No pattern. Stops   I turn it off and in a few minutes it goes again. All dash warning lights come on. Toyota cannot figure it out. It's been on two computers.

Comment: Is your Check Engine light on? If so, see if you can get the code read out. Either your smart phone with a $15 US adapter from eBay can do it. Or, go to many of the local parts stores here in the US anyway, that will read the code for free. Then let us know what it is..

Answer (score 3):

It could be

1. crank sensor is failing- test and replace
2. fuel filter clogged- replace it
3. fuel pump- test and replace

There are many possibilities though.

Intermittent die outs can very difficult to diagnose by anyone.